# How to do soft delete in feathersJs using mongoose for mongoDb database

Tags: node.js, mongoose, feathersjs, soft-delete

I want to implement the soft delete feature in the project I am working on currently. The project is using feathersjs and mongoose. If anybody is having any idea how to implement it inside feathers hooks

Comment: Definition of soft-delete.<br/>An easy way to keep deleted data in your database. "Soft delete" in database lingo means that you set a flag on an existing table which indicates that a record has been deleted, instead of actually deleting the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use hooks collection created by feathers community [feathers-hooks-common](https://hooks-common.feathersjs.com/hooks.html#softdelete)

use **npm install feathers-hooks-common** to import it in our library.

```
 import {softDelete} from 'feathers-hooks-common';

    export default {
      before: {
        all: [
//it takes an object as its parameter. in this case i passed an empty object
      softDelete({}),
    ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
      }
    }
```

also add deleted field of type `boolean` in your schema